# How to config remark's plugins in gatsby-transformer-remark

Tags: gatsby, remarkjs

I want to use remark with "remark-breaks" (or any other plugins). 
I tried this in gatsby-config.js:

```
 ...        
  {
  resolve: "gatsby-transformer-remark",
  options: {
    plugins: [
      {
         resolve: "remark-breaks",
      }, 
      // "remark-breaks", //this doesn't work either.        
    ] 
  }
```

It said:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'Parser' of undefined
>
> - index.js:6 breaks
>     [demo]/[remark-breaks]/index.js:6:21
> - extend-node-type.js:142
>     [demo]/[gatsby-transformer-remark]/extend-node-type.js:142:32

I can see that only gatsby's plugin may be used like this. Then how can I config remark with plugins of its own?

Answer (score 0):

Since a Gatsby remark plugin doesn't already exist for `remark-breaks` you'd have to look into developing your own: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/plugin-authoring/